# Resque scheduled jobs are stuck in pending queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, resque-scheduler

I'm creating a DripEmail campaign for my app and using resque scheduler to schedule the tasks.

I've sceduled a static job, which runs every day at a specific time and collect the user's list based on the drip settings and sends out an emailer to them.

This is my resque job `user_follow_up.rb`

```
class UserFollowUp
    @queue = :user_follow_up
    def self.perform
        User.each do |u|
            # Send the emailers to only those who are not converted
            if !user.is_converted and Date.today <= user.next_email
                stage(u)
            end
        end
    end 
end
```

This is my `scheduler.yml`

```
UserFollowUp:
  cron: "0 16 * * *"
```

I have 2 resque workers, one has my default set of tasks and the other for scheduler.

```
rake environment resque:work QUEUE=publish_story,accept_story,image_queue,Mango_mailer
```

and

```
rake environment resque:scheduler QUEUE=user_follow_up
```

[image: Resque static jobs]

When I open the resque admin interface, I'm able to see my static job detected in the list. I clicked the `Queue Now` button to test it. It properly enqueues the task to the queue, but doesn't execute. It keeps these tasks in the pending queue forever.

[image: Jobs stuck in queue]

This is my `resque.rake`, it's required

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'
require 'resque/scheduler/server'
require 'active_record'
require 'mongoid'
require 'action_controller/railtie'
require 'active_support/buffered_logger'


# load the Rails app all the time

    namespace :resque do
        puts 'Loading Rails environment for Resque'
        task :setup => :environment do
            # The schedule doesn't need to be stored in a YAML, it just needs to
            # be a hash.  YAML is usually the easiest.
            Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/scheduler.yml")
            Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true
            Resque.logger.info 'Resque Scheduler Initialized!'
            Resque.before_first_fork do
                # Open the new separate log file
                logfile = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'resque.log'), 'a')
                # Activate file synchronization
                logfile.sync = true
                # Create a new buffered logger
                Resque.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(logfile)
                Resque.logger.level = Logger::INFO
                Resque.logger.info 'Resque Logger Initialized!'
                puts 'Resque Logger Initialized!'
            end
        end
        task 'resque:pool:setup' do
            Resque::Pool.after_prefork do |job|
                Resque.redis.client.reconnect
            end
        end
    end
```

And this is my Gemfile

```
gem 'resque',  github: 'resque/resque' , branch: '1-x-stable'
gem 'resque_mailer', github: 'zapnap/resque_mailer'
gem 'resque-scheduler'
```

I'm not sure what is the issue here. Please help me with this fix.

Comment: Are you sure that your workers are running?